# Does Newtonian physics work on a galactic scale?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

I'm currently working on a simulation that aims to use Newton's Law of Gravitation to simulate how a galaxy behaves gravitationally. While I haven't gotten the simulation finished yet, I have had a few people tell me that Newtonian Physics don't work on a galactic scale, and that I need a different model to accurately simulate a galaxy gravitationally.

Is this true?

Comment: Yes if you believe in dark matter, no if you're a fan of MOND or some-such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  Newtonian Physics works on a galactic scale.

Still, for long distance interactions on fast objects you might want to take into account the finite speed of gravity, but I don't think it is necessary for ordinary galaxies simulations. 
Conversly a lot of phenomena occur that impact the galactic material: writting a decent simulation is not easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What kind of phenomenon would I have to take into account when writing the simulation?

Comment: One might add that newtonian physics emerges from  underlying General Relativity laws, but GR effects are  too 'weak' to be necessary to explore the mathematics for gallactic computations ( in contrast for the GPS system  where great accuracy is necessary, the corrections are important)

Comment: Ethan: first, which kind of solver do you plan to use ? SPH ? second: you will need to use a coarse resolution compare to objects. gaz condense or advect, stars migrates, so your particles have to exchange material. this is fluidish but not totally. there are also birth and depth of stars that modify the content (amount, nature and velocity of gaz). BTW stars and gaz don't travel at the same speed. Black matter is required, some people wonder whether magnetic fields could count.

Comment: Whilst I am no fan of MOND, I do think it unwise to be quite so dogmatic. Newtonian gravity may work on very large scales, if we also accept dark matter. Or it may have a problem when at the very large scales, as the MOND proponents claim.

Comment: well, physics is about models, and many galactic simulations do work with pure newtonian physics acting on a mix of star particles, gaz particles and black matter particles, which was quite the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, Newton's Second Law of motion is only an approximation and doesn't work on anything larger than a solar system.  When you get into the domain where the acceleration is on the order of $10^{-14}\space km\space s^{-2}$, then you can see limits of the approximation.  Stars at the edges of spiral galaxies travel much too fast to be governed by Newton's Second Law of Motion.  Even backfilling a galaxy with some imaginary matter won't fix the problem.  Take a look at the data for [Andromeda](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.3846v1) and you'll see a rising velocity curve beyond 30 kpc that clearly conflicts with the predicted Newtonian decay.

The second law can be easily fixed, however:

$$\sum_{i} F_i = m(a_F + a_0)$$
$$a_0 = 3.74\times 10^{-14}\space km\space s^{-2}$$
Applying this to a circular orbit gives:
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{M G}{r} + a_0r} $$
Where $a_F$ is the acceleration of the unbalancing force (gravity in the case of an orbiting star) and $a_0$ is the constant acceleration of the expansion of the universe.  Go ahead and try it!  It will fix any velocity curve problem you have without resorting to science fiction.

Comment: This is non mainstream physics and as such it does not belong on this site. The velocity curves have a well established explanation in the form of dark matter.

Comment: Javier - If you haven't been paying attention to the news, LUX and $Xenon_{500}$ have ruled out any rational grounds for dark matter.  In addition, the Higgs Boson discovered at the LHC appears to be the Standard Model Higgs Boson, which effectively eliminates SUSY.  Your 'mainstream' cosmology has no rational foundation in particle science.  The equation above is 'disprovable'.  So if you are a scientists, then disprove it.

Comment: Two brief comments. As far as I can tell those experiments are looking for WIMPs, which are not the only candidate for dark matter, and the LHC has most definitely *not* ruled out SUSY. And just because I can't disprove your theory doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: I said it has 'effectively' ruled out SUSY.  The odds of supersymmetry existing in some form is about the same as purple unicorns.  So while I can't say for certain that purple unicorns are the source of missing mass, I would certainly be irrational for trying to base a cosmology on such a principle.

Comment: And as far as my formula goes, this is how science works: You form a theory then someone tries to disprove it.  If it's disproven, that's the end of the theory.  The longer something lasts without being disproven, the more authority it has as a theory.  I've provided a simple formula based on an expanding universe.  If you don't believe it has a place on this forum, then it should be a simple matter to disprove it and we can settle this like scientists.

Comment: The satellites of Andromeda lie at radii of 100kpc+, yet all have line of sight velocities wrt Andromeda <120 km/s. In contrast, your model predicts an enormous velocity for these satellites, rising as $r^{1/2}$ from a minimum of about 200 km/s at 20 kpc.

Comment: Evans & Wilkinson (2000).    http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.316..929E Hardly new results.

Comment: MOND is more subtle than a simple additive term.

Comment: My understanding is that galaxies in a group or cluster behave like a virialized system, not like a spiral galaxy.  If there's evidence that these dwarves are locked in a circular orbit, then I missed it and would appreciate being educated on the subject.  Otherwise, it appears to me that the proper treatment of these satellites is to treat them as members of a virialized system and look at the average dispersion of the group.

Comment: Makes no difference at all. Or does your additional acceleration "know" what trajectory something is on?

Comment: What makes no difference at all?  The formula for velocity given above is only valid for a (near) circular orbit.  If the satellites are buzzing around M31 like bees around a hive, then you need some other approach, like the Virial Theorem.  My cursory search shows that you can't calculate the mass of a galaxy from it's satellites because they all give different answers.  If you've got something that says different, I'd love to look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32281/discussion-between-rob-jeffries-and-donald-roy-airey).